# The TEdit.Height is fixed on Firemonkey Style, How to change it?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am using a regular Firemonkey HD application and decided to use only the 
style that comes with MetropolisUI (just the style, it is not Metropolis app/form since I need it to be cross platform)

The problem is that TEdit is set to a fixed size, that is for me too big.

I have played to change the style by StyleBook, was not successful. I am 
newbie with styles and firemonkey.

Have tested other option incluing Chris Holliston using the interposer 
class.

However I need to reduce the height at design time, since I have many fields 
and the positioning is critical

Please, I would like to know the steps to change that (I was using the 
editstyle on TEdit.LookupStyle from MetropoliUIBlue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a last resource I have decided to open the MetropolisUI.Style on notepad and take a look on what is inside.

I have found that "editstyle" that is the default for TEdit has the following structure:

```
object TLayout
    StyleName = 'editstyle'
    Height = 50.000000000000000000
    Width = 50.000000000000000000
    FixedHeight = 32
```

As we can see there is this FixedHeight.

I could not find that on the Style Editor.

Removing that tag FixedHeight, saving and load the style back again to StyleBook enabled me to change the height freely.